# Kendo Grid for MVC, Update action is not firing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

After going through numerous articles on stack overflow and google ,

I think the problem is with my Model,
I have tried lots of things, like making all of the fields editable, giving default value of id as 160000 etc., but could not make it work

Can you please identify and let me know, what should I do to make this work

Kendo Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BuyUpRatesVM>()
                                        .Name("grdBuyUpRates")
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(d => d.RateQuoteBuyUpConfigIdNh).Hidden();

                                            columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ConfigDetlIdNh, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["StateIssuer"], "ConfigDetlId", "StateIssuer")
                                                        .Title("State/Issuer").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "State/Issuer" }).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= StateHyphenIssuer #" }).Width("20%");

                                            columns.Bound(d => d.EffectiveDate).Title("Effective Date").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Effective Date" }).EditorTemplateName("date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= EffectiveDate #" }).Width("20%");
                                            columns.Bound(d => d.ExpirtaionDate).Title("Expiration Date").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Expiration Date" }).EditorTemplateName("date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= ExpirtaionDate #" }).Width("20%");

                                            columns.ForeignKey(d => d.RateTypeLookUpId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["RateType"], "RateTypeLookUpIdDD", "RateTypeLookUpValueDD")
                                                         .Title("Rate").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Rate" }).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= RateTypelookUpValue #" }).Width("20%");

                                            columns.Bound(d => d.Amount).Title("Amount").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Amount" }).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= Amount #" }).Width("20%");

                                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Title("Action").Width(65);
                                        })
                                        .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true).Refresh(true))
                                        .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
                                        .Excel(excel => excel
                                            .FileName(@timetstamp)
                                            .Filterable(true)
                                            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export", "Common")).AllPages(true))
                                        .Sortable()
                                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax()
                                            .PageSize(10)
                                            //.Sort(s => s.Add("StateLookUpName"))
                                            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateBuyUpRates", controller))
                                            .Model(model =>
                                            {
                                                model.Id(p => p.RateQuoteBuyUpConfigIdNh);
                                            })
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetBuyUpRates", controller)))
                                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)).AutoBind(true)

            )
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult GetBuyUpRates([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var oob = _configuration.GetBuyUpRates();
        DataSourceResult lstArtifact = oob.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(lstArtifact);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UpdateBuyUpRates([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, BuyUpRatesVM p_BuyUpRatesVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (p_BuyUpRatesVM != null)
            {
                p_BuyUpRatesVM = _configuration.UpdateBuyUpRates(p_BuyUpRatesVM, StateManager.LoggedUserIdRx);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_BuyUpRatesVM.ErrorMessage))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", p_BuyUpRatesVM.ErrorMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new[] { p_BuyUpRatesVM }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new[] { p_BuyUpRatesVM }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Model Class

```
public class BuyUpRatesVM
{
    public decimal RateQuoteBuyUpConfigIdNh { get; set; }
    public decimal ConfigDetlIdNh { get; set; }
    public decimal ConfigIdNh { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string IssuerId { get; set; }
    public string StateHyphenIssuer { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirtaionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal RateTypeLookUpId { get; set; }
    public string RateTypelookUpValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change kendo

> form.dirty

sample code and more information on this link[here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-popup-edit)